# Nginx: Tracking try_files misses

Tags: nginx, cache, uwsgi, statistics

We are using try_files as cache rather than hitting the UWSGI to serve the file. Using a rule like the following:

```
try_files $uri @uwsgi_app;
```

I was wondering what is the best way of logging the cache success of this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by manually searching both the UWSGI and nginx logs to find the differences for requests on resources to build a rough cache hit percentage.